# how to add new column to a dataframe and add the data to it row by row

Tags: python

I have a dataframe df and want to add a new column at the end of it and I want add data to this new column by one row at a time and not the complete column at once. Here is part of my current data frame:

```
row number,type,rcvTime,sender,pos_x,pos_y,pos_z,spd_x,spd_y,spd_z,acl_x,acl_y,acl_z,hed_x,hed_y,hed_z
0,2,25202.0,9,265.12,50.64,0.0,-0.08,0.73,0.0,-0.23,2.21,0.0,-0.1,0.99,0.0
1,2,25203.0,9,265.17,52.59,0.0,-0.3,2.89,0.0,-0.19,1.8,0.0,-0.09,1.0,0.0
2,2,25204.0,9,264.69,56.5,0.0,-0.52,4.82,0.0,-0.19,1.74,0.0,-0.1,1.0,0.0
3,2,25205.0,9,263.68,62.38,0.0,-0.88,6.76,0.0,-0.26,1.97,0.0,-0.12,0.99,0.0
...
```

What I need to do is, in this DataFrame, row by row, I have to read the sender value as key from a dictionary and extract its value and add this value into the new column for that sender. The new dataframe should look like this:

```
row number,type,rcvTime,sender,pos_x,pos_y,pos_z,spd_x,spd_y,spd_z,acl_x,acl_y,acl_z,hed_x,hed_y,hed_z,label
0,2,25202.0,9,265.12,50.64,0.0,-0.08,0.73,0.0,-0.23,2.21,0.0,-0.1,0.99,0.0,1
1,2,25203.0,9,265.17,52.59,0.0,-0.3,2.89,0.0,-0.19,1.8,0.0,-0.09,1.0,0.0,0
2,2,25204.0,9,264.69,56.5,0.0,-0.52,4.82,0.0,-0.19,1.74,0.0,-0.1,1.0,0.0,1
3,2,25205.0,9,263.68,62.38,0.0,-0.88,6.76,0.0,-0.26,1.97,0.0,-0.12,0.99,0.0,0
...
```

Actually, this new column has the label for each row. Here is what I have tried but doesn't work:

```
i=0
for i in range(len(df)):
        matcha = a_dict.get(df.iloc[i].iat[3])
        df.loc[i, 'level'] =matcha
df.to_csv('/Users/tt/file_name.csv', encoding='utf-8',index=False)
```

I also tried to make a list of labels and then assign that list to the df but again in csv file I can not the new column:

```
i=0
for i in range(len(df)):
    matcha = a_dict.get(df.iloc[i].iat[3])
    dfNewColList.append(matcha)
    df.assign(labels=dfNewColList)
```

Comment: You can first create a list of labels based on your condition and finally add that list to the dataframe.

Comment: column can't have only one value - you may have to put some default value in all rows and later add correct value only in one row.

Comment: Could you provide me an example? I didn't understand well what you mean

Answer (score 0):

The below code worked

```
import pandas as pd
 
# A sample dictionary containing Students data
data = {'Name': ['Jai', 'Princi', 'Gaurav', 'Anuj'],
        'Height': [5.1, 6.2, 5.1, 5.2],
        'Qualification': ['Msc', 'MA', 'Msc', 'Msc']}
 
# A sample dataframe 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
 
i=0
a_dict = {5.1:0, 6.2:1, 5.2:2} # I don't know what is your a_dict so created one of mine.

for i in range(len(df)):
  print(df.iloc[i].iat[1])
  matcha = a_dict.get(df.iloc[i].iat[1])
  print(matcha)
  df.loc[i, 'level'] = matcha
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I wrote exactly the same as your code then later I convert df to csv file but I can not see the new column and its data. I updated my code in the above.